# Shorten jQuery script on Resize

Tags: jquery, resize

I have two opposite scripts, and would like to know if they can be compiled in one :

```
/* Display left picture of Pirlo */
if ($(window).width()  > 910)   
  $('.picture').css('display','block');
else
  $('.picture').css('display','none');  

/* Hide Mugshot of Pirlo */
if ($(window).width()  > 910)   
  $('.mugshot').css('display','none');
else
  $('.mugshot').css('display','block');
```

Here is the template : http://bettercheckthekids.com/pirlo/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($(window).width()  > 910){
  $('.picture').show();
  $('.mugshot').hide();
} else {
  $('.picture').hide();
  $('.mugshot').show();
}
```

If you are just hiding and showing elements based on the width of the viewport, this can also be done using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: yeah, but this is dedicated to javascript or non-javascript runners

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(window).width()  > 910)   
{
  $('.picture').css('display','block');
  $('.mugshot').css('display','none');
}
else
{
  $('.picture').css('display','none');  
  $('.mugshot').css('display','block');
}
```